# pie chart highcharts from django query

Tags: django, postgresql, highcharts, pie-chart, dataformat

I am running a query in views.py in a django environment. All is currently running local with the idea to push it finally into a heroku environment. I use PostgreSQL.

```
def test(request):
    click_results = clickstats.objects.filter(user=request.user.username, urlid=pk_int)
    data = parse_data_browser(request, click_results)
    template = get_template('index.html')
    context = {
    'data': data,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def parse_data_browser(request,click_results):

    browsers = click_results.values('browser').annotate(browser_qty=Count('browser')).order_by()
    print("browsers")
    print(browsers)
    return browsers
```

the printed output by `parse_data_browser` looks like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'browser': 'Chrome Mobile', 'browser_qty': 4}, {'browser': 'Chrome', 'browser_qty': 9}]>
```

the challenge is to get it in this shape:

```
data = [{name: 'Chrome Mobile', y: 4}, {name: 'Chrome', y: 9}]
```

then passing it on to my index.html using following scripts:

```
<script>
    var chart_id = {{ chartID|safe }}
    var chart = {{ chart|safe }}
    var title = {{ title|safe }}
    var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }}
    var data = {{ data|safe }}
</script>
```

and finally create the chart with this script:

```
<script>
$(function () { 
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('chartID', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{name: 'Chrome Mobile', y: 4}, {name: 'Chrome', y: 9}]
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried multiple things with dict and append functions, but nothing does give the right output.

What is the best approach. I would rather not start stacking output-json files on my environment as that seems one way to go.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can iterate on the query and build a list:

```
data = [{'name': item['browser'], 'y': item['browser_qty'] }
         for item in parse_data_browser_result.all() ]
```

This is called a list comprehension.

Or you can still pass the queryset to the template and build the data like this:

```
data: [
    {% for item in data.all() %}
        {% if total > 0 %}
            { name: "{{ item['browser'] }}", y: {{ item['browser_qty'] }} },
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
]
```

inside the `<script>`.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! great help! had to do some modifications as `item.browser` returned an `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'browser'` and did a workaround like this: `data = [{'name': item['browser'], 'y': item['browser_qty'] } for item in browsers ]`  -  don't like the templates in my html, very messy :-)

Comment: ah yes, of course it's a dict, will update my answer. Happy to have helped you :)